# Create dataframes or vectors from each variable or column of a data frame

Tags: r

So, as the question is stated, I tried the below approach:

```r
library(rlang)
nam <- names(iris)
iris[,nam[1]]


dfs <- function(x,y){
  x1 <- get(x)
 df <- x1[,y]
  assign(y,df,pos=-1, envir = globalenv())
}

purrr::map2('iris', nam, dfs)
```

This will generate the vectors of the individual column of the dataframe passed.

However, here I used the dataframe name iris as a parameter where I am passing a quoted string.
I wish to know if I can pass a non quoted string and get the same result.

```
purrr::map2(iris, nam, dfs)
```

Comment: Thank you I updated the code, this works. Please  check

Comment: You can define your function as `dfs <- function(x, y) assign(y, x, envir = .GlobalEnv)` and call it with `purrr::walk2(iris, nam, dfs)` but this is a roundabout way of just doing `list2env(iris, .GlobalEnv)`.  But you really shouldn't be cluttering your global environment this way.  What are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you, the walk2 is really good. I am trying to achieve the same via the function i wrote, reason being that i want to understand how i can pass the data frame name as unquoted parameter, like how we passed in walk2, but i want to achieve the same via map2, so how i can modify the function

Comment: Why `iris[,nam] |> as.list()` doesn't suit you?

Answer (score 0):

I would offer the following:

```
function_to_apply_to_list <- function(x) x # do whatever you want with data or just return x

foo <- function(x, y, .f){ # replacement of map2
  x[,y] |> as.list() |> lapply(.f)
}

foo(iris, nam, function_to_apply_to_list)
```